# Does anyone know of a machinist who could convert a dual ring Campy Nuovo Record chainset ('spider') to accept a 3rd chainring?

Tags: crankset, campagnolo, modification

I have a 1971 Raleigh International whose Campagnolo Nuovo Record chainset has Campy pedals that are 'frozen' into their threads (I know, this is an instance of neglected maintenance).  I really like this bike and its components - pedals included - and would like to have lower gearing than typically possible with a 2-ring chainset (have 42 rear/34 front, now). I'm looking for a master bike machinist who could tap an additional set of 5 holes to accept the 5 sleeves for a triple crankset?

Comment: OK, I meant to say, I have 42 FRONT/34 REAR for lowest gearing.

Comment: I have to wonder whether there would even be enough room for an extra chainring on the inside edge or a crank that was only designed as a double. If you really like your components that much, it might be worth checking eBay for a triple chainset that matches your components.

Comment: Old bikes have much bigger clearances than modern bikes, there's a reasonable chance it will all just work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drilling a crank that old is not a great idea. They weren't that strong to begin with and 40+ years of use hasn't made then any stronger. I would not do anything to further weaken them.

To be honest, if the pedals are frozen I'd think twice about using that crank. Aluminum corrosion expands and can create stress that crack the material ( similar to the way ice can expand and split a crack in a boulder).

All that aside, if you look hard enough you can find a "tripleizer" ring. This is a special inner ring that 
includes the mounts for a smaller inner ring.

[image: Close up of TA Tripleizer]

[Vintage Trek Tripleizer Page](http://www.vintage-trek.com/tripleizer.htm)

On a bike that old, there's a reasonable chance that you won't need a new bottom 
bracket to allow the inner ring to clear the chainstays. Also, there's a pretty good chance the existing derailler cage will be low enough to allow use of the small chainring. Back then there was no such thing as a "triple" front derailluer.

Shifting will require a bit of practice compared to modern triples; you will drop the 
chain, so get a Dog Fang or other chain catcher.

If you want components that are modern but look old and don't cost the insane price of
used campagnolo on Ebay; Check out [Velo Orange Components](http://www.velo-orange.com) This should bring back some
memories.

[image: 48/34 Drillium Crank]

That crank is a 34/48 that I think would be a really good choice for an upgrade on a older bike.

Answer (score 0):

Tap another 5 holes is not enough.  There needs to be metal to space it out that I suspect is not there.  Just add a spacer would probably not handle the load.

Even if you do attach are you sure there is room on the bike?

Are sure you can find triple front derailleur for that bike?

If you get past all that you may end up with chain line issues.

Look at getting a bigger cassette.